Choosen database is not used when using postgresql with docker
I am new to docker.I have written a docker-compose.yaml with following :
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: suman
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - network_establish
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT: 5432  # Define port for PostgreSQL
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    networks:
      - network_establish
networks:
  network_establish:
    name: network_establish
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:

And in my springboot application.properties I have defined
spring.application.name=mapping

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jpamapping
spring.datasource.username=suman
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

where I defined url as

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jpamapping

The problem is when opening pgadmin and registering server.It default creates 2 database:postgres and suman.Now instead of using jpamapping database(which I created from init.sql) to queries it creates all table inside suman database.Can anyone assist me where I am doing wrong??As it should use jpamapping database if I tell in application.properties

- ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

is not really necessary if you add POSTGRES_DB: jpamapping.
